# Validate client app instead of access_token on some actions in doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, doorkeeper

I'm using Rails JSON API + Doorkeeper, so I want to let my mobile app that has client_id and client_secrete to request POST /users to create a user without validating with access token. Currently, I create user directly in rails console, and mobile application uses Using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow to get token to access protected resources via API. In this code below, mobile application has to provide access token to be able to invoke index action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  doorkeeper_for :all, except: :create

  def index
    ...
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

Currently, create action doesn't validate anything, so is there anyway to tell door_keeper to validate client_id and client_secret before allowing to invoke a particular action? I don't want it to be public.

Comment: OAuth provides an api client access to protected resources authorized by the owner of those resources.  Are you asking for something that authorizes your client to use your api independently of any resource owner?  OAuth works by requiring a resource owner to grant permission. Client secret and client key don't help with a mobile app, because inspection of the app reveals them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782527/doorkeeper-without-web-views also wants to create users. I don't think OAuth helps.